# x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 not working

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, visual-studio-2019

I am facing this weird issue whith Native tools cmd for VS 2019. Everytime I try to open any cmd of VS 2019 (Native tools or cross tools cmd) the following screen appears and the system exhibits weird behavior. 
I am unable to close this cmd. I can't open task manager. However if the task manager is opened before opening VS cmd then I can kill this process using task manager. Even after closing it, I am unable to shut down my laptop as the left mouse button and enter button stops working.
Is this some kind of bug or error in my system or has anyone else faced the same issue?[image: VS 2019 native tools cmd]

Comment: Add your computer configuration